# TypeError: unsupported operand type-python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to fix the issue below for long time.I am trying to get a reponse like 200,401 eyc.It  will be great if you could take a quick look at the code below.I tried in two different way,but none works as indicated inside the block.I will really appreciate if someone could help me.

```
"head="/questions/ask"
 host = "stackoverflow.com"
 port = 80
 try:
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 except socket.error, msg:
 sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
 sys.exit(1) 
 try:
 sock.connect((host, port))
 except socket.error, msg:
 sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1]) 
 sys.exit(2)


 sock.send("HEAD  %s  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")%(head)
 #this one gives me error"   sock.send("HEAD head1 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")%(head)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'", my Url is string!

 sock.send("HEAD  head  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
 #gives error 404

 s=sock.recv(12)
 print s
 sock.close()
 sys.exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sock.send("HEAD  %s  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")%(head)
```

should be

```
sock.send("HEAD  %s  HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" % head)
```

Does that make sense? It's an order of operations thing - right now the sending happens first, returning an integer, on which you're trying to use `%` for string formatting - but on integers that operator gives you the modulus, which needs another number after it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help!I really appreciate. that worked and made sense! I don't get that error any more, but it still gives me return of 400, even if it is a right url. Then if I paste my url it works fine.But for my program I need to be able to send the link through a variable head.Any suggestion?